# How to convert from TimePrimitive to int?

Tags: java

I have some data values(of type TimePrimitive) which i need to write out  to a file , but the method out.write() takes only the parameter as int so i need to find a way to convert my values to int

Comment: looks more like Java than Javascript.

Comment: Maybe you can get us a hint what TimePrimitive is for a type? Did you write it yourself, or does it come from a library? Which one? Because TimePrimitive isn't in the Java API.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the wrong approach.  If you want to write objects to a file, then you need to use an ObjectOutputStream to write to the file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeInt(12345);
oos.writeObject("Today");
oos.writeObject(new Date());
    oos.writeObject(myTimePrimitive);
oos.close();
```

The normal out.write(int) is used to write a simple byte to a stream, and it would be implicitely be used by the ObjectOutputStream class.

You can use an ObjectInputStream to read your object back.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the getValue() method?

BTW, What platform are you using, Javascript itself does not have a TimePrimitive type, are you sure this isn't Java?

Comment: yeah , sorry I just entered Javascript by mistake, it is Java, the method getValue() did work but it gives me this exception >>java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: sorry the method getValue() didn't work, so any other suggestion?